# Load an XIB from a view controller of another XIB (iPhone)

Tags: iphone, crash, load, xib

This is my first post and I'm pretty new to this stuff but here is my question and I hope you can help :)

So I made a game screen and now want to add a Main Menu to the beginning. So I added a new View Controller Subclass and now have an IBAction that is from a button that will load the game screen.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface MainMenuViewController : UIViewController{
  IBOutlet  UIButton *classicMode;
  IBOutlet  UIButton *timedMode;
}    

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *classicMode; 
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *timedMode; 



- (IBAction) classicModeButton:(id) sender;
- (IBAction) timedModeButton:(id) sender;
@end
```

So now I went into my .m and set the IBAction

```
- (IBAction) classicModeButton:(id)sender{


}
```

But I've tried using initWithNibName and specifying my other view controller xib, and it runs with no errors, but when I tap the button I have linked in IB it always crashes and says that it received the signal SIGABRT. Any help would be greatly appreciated. :)

Comment: Can you post your initWithNibName method?

Comment: probably, the `view` is `nil` in your `UIViewController`. please, check **[this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11906618/loading-xib-crashes-app/11906907#11906907)**, it might help you.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably hitting the problem described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5750766/why-does-this-different-addsubview-code-cause-differences-in-behavior) post. You need to set your controller as self.window.rootViewController instead of adding it as subview of the self.window in your app delegate code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to post more of your code but you most likely need to create a navigation controller to push the view controller onto.  The navigation controller manages the transition of views so is necessary to perform switches from one view to another.